# Ionic side menu not working

Tags: ionic-framework

```
<ion-side-menus>

        <ion-side-menu-content>

          <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">

          <button class="button icon-left ion-navicon-round button-clear " menu-toggle="left"> </button>

          <h1 class="title">Maalish</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>

        </ion-side-menu-content>

        <ion-side-menu side="left">

        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            Home
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>
```

i tried using this code but the navigation bar doesnt simply show niether does the slidemenu I am using the latest ionic version

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways of approaching this.

1. Either use`$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();` in your controller (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/)
2. Or Use the menu-toggle directive (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuToggle/) in your home view.

Answer (score 0):

First, please use `ion-nav-bar` instead `ion-header-bar` in `ion-side-menu-content`, and then set `ion-nav-view` as container for menu items detail:

```
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon-round" menu-toggle="left">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content> 

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item menu-close href=**link to your detail page**>
                Home
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>
```

- `name="menuContent"` should be defined in you views state file, generally `app.js`.
- The directive `menu-close` is optional, use it if you want to close side menu automatically after click the menu item.